# How to create a custom Api endpoint in the superset and integrate it with superset. How does superset recognize api

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, apache-superset

I have created a custom api endpoint in new .py file and added that api to the initialization file such as appbuilder.add_api(Api). But still superset is not registering that api.Iam getting internal server error.

I tried to register an api by the appbuilder.add_api(Api) in the **init**.py file and then run the server.From the front end iam trying to post the request to the created api endpoint.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

in Superset version 3.1.0 I did it by the following way.

**folder structure**

```
superset
- docker
-- python_path_dev
--- custom
---- __init__.py
---- api.py
---- superset_config.py
```

****init**.py**

```
def flask_app_mutator(app):
    from flask import redirect, url_for
    from superset import appbuilder
    from custom.api import ChartApi

    #
    # Setup API
    #
    appbuilder.add_api(ChartApi)
```

**api.py**

```
from flask_appbuilder.api import expose, protect
from superset.views.base_api import BaseSupersetApi

class ChartApi(BaseSupersetApi):
    print("### custom.ChartApi loaded ###")

    resource_name = 'custom/chart'
    include_route_methods = {"hello"}

    @expose('/hello', methods=("GET",))
    def hello(self):
        return self.response(200, message="hello world")
```

**superset_config.py**

```
...
# end of file
# Customization
from custom import flask_app_mutator
FLASK_APP_MUTATOR = flask_app_mutator
```

run `docker compose up -d`

go to browser and open `http://localhost:8088/api/v1/custom/chart/hello`